# Error while testing an Angular component with router events

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

In my component, I use router events to display a loader.

I encounter many errors. I guess it's because, on testBed, the component doesn't manage to get real router events.

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

**How can I "mock" the events to be remove these errors and being able to test my loader method? If not possible, how to make Angular to ignore this part returning him a fake event?**

#### Component.ts

```
constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private r: Router
  ) {

    // Listen for router events to trigger the page loader
    r.events.
      filter(e => this.isStart(e) || this.isEnd(e)).
      map(e => this.isStart(e)).
      distinctUntilChanged().
      subscribe(showLoader => {
        if (showLoader) {
          this.loaderService.start();
        } else {
          this.loaderService.complete();
        }
    });
  }

  // Router events functions
  isStart(e): boolean {
    return e instanceof NavigationStart;
  }

  isEnd(e): boolean {
    return e instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      e instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      e instanceof NavigationError;
  }

  collectAllEventsForNavigation(obs: Observable<Event>):
    Observable<Event[]> {
    let observer: Observer<Event[]>;
    const events = [];
    const sub = obs.subscribe(e => {
      events.push(e);
      if (this.isEnd(e)) {
        observer.next(events);
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
    return new Observable<Event[]>(o => observer = o);
  }
```

#### component.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        Component,
        RouterLinkStubDirective,
        RouterOutletStubComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        AppLoaderService,
        LoaderService,
        Router
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    comp    = fixture.componentInstance;


    // trigger initial data binding
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // find DebugElements with an attached RouterLinkStubDirective
    linkDes = fixture.debugElement
      .queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkStubDirective));

    // get the attached link directive instances using the DebugElement injectors
    links = linkDes
      .map(de => de.injector.get(RouterLinkStubDirective) as RouterLinkStubDirective);

});
```

If I remove from constructor the `r.events.[...]` code, errors disappear.

Comment: Try using `{ provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }` as described here https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-routes-in-angular-2

Comment: I know I can create a stub, I already tried. But mocking/stubbing the event part of router is the part I struggle doing. Here is my current stub: https://pastebin.com/esyNSEf6

Comment: What is about `RouterTestingModule`?

Comment: Do I need to import and then provide `import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';` ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/router/test/integration.spec.ts#L25

Comment: Yes that's correct path

Comment: Ok I got it imported but error still shows about r.event methods

Comment: I just want to add my error here for search engine indexing.  My issue was an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" that I couldn't work out. But solution here filtering for NavigationError gave me insight in to where to look (because the error wasn't based on any split() method call I was making in my code.  Finding this note, and the above example code might help others.